C# Winforms custom ColorEditor for UserControl
I have a few colors in my Application and i want to be able to set them and only them as BackColor and other properties. So i wanted to create a CustomColor Editor but I can not manage to run it.
I use winforms in .net8. I found several solutions bot none worked.
How can I override ColorUI class of ColorEditor class and add a new Tab with custom colors?
https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/4304

It would seem that github link is the ultimate authority on the subject.

How to write WinForms Designers in NET 6.0 -- When you decorate the relevant Property(ies), also try without specifying, in the attribute, typeof(UITypeEditor) as the base class of your custom editor
